# silverlight app realtime update design

Tags: winforms, silverlight-4.0, service

I have a winform app, which takes live image from an ip camera, and detect vehicle license plate number from the image. Now i want to make a silverlight app which can connect to my winform app or some kind of service app, and the silverlight app gets updated whenever a new license plate number is detected, what service/architect should i use to make this possible?

Thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your going to need the following...

An IIS server that exposes a WCF service. Your Silverlight application can be running in any browser in any location and from time to time it needs to poll for new data by making a request to the WCF service asking for the latest updates. Your WinForm application can send new data to the WCF service whenever it has new data. The WCF service running in IIS acts as the buffer that caches the incoming updates from your WinForms application that passes it back to any number of Silverlight clients that request the latest data.

Comment: what if i host the WCF service in the winform app?

Comment: will not work because your Silverlight app will not know how to location and access the WinForm application.